# BS4 text inside <span> which has no class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape this 4.1 rating in span tag using this python code but it is returning empty.

```
for item in soup.select("._9uwBC wY0my"):
        n = soup.find("span").text()
        print(n)
---------------------------------------

<div class="_9uwBC wY0my">
      <span class="icon-star _537e4"></span>
      <span>4.1</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's one approach for getting the names and stars for each restaurant on the page. It's not necessarily the most elegant way to do it, but I've tried it a couple of times and it seems to work:

```
divs = soup.find_all('div')

for div in divs:
    if div.has_attr('class'):
        if div['class'] == ['nA6kb']: ## the class of the divs with the name
            name = div.text
            k = div.find_next('div') ## the next div
            l = k.find_next('div')  ## the div with the stars
            spans = l.find_all('span') ## this part is same as the answer above
            for span in spans:
                n = span.text
                if n != '':
                    print(name, n)
```

This assumes that the div that contains the stars span is always the second div after the div that contains the restaurant name. It looks like that's always the case, but I'm not positive that it never changes.

Comment: It is awesome it is working fine Thank you so much man.

Answer (score 2):

@Aditya, I think soup.find("span") will only return the first "span" and you want the text from the second one.
I would try:

```
for item in soup.select("div._9uwBC.wY0my"):
    spans = item.find_all("span")
    for span in spans:
        n = span.text
        if n != '':
            print(n)
```

Which should print the text of the non-empty span tags, under the  you specified.
Does accomplish what you want?

Comment: ohh thanks, yeah it returned text from every span tag.

Comment: @Aditya try putting it back inside your 'soup.select' loop ... I'm not sure what else is on the page, but if there is only one div with the _9uwBC wY0my class attributes, it should work. If there are lots of divs like that, then, unfortunately, this approach will print a lot of span.text that you don't want.

Comment: yes, I somehow scraped those ratings among all those noises from every span tag but unfortunately, I am having problem matching it with my data points like so do you know any other approach which can only return that exact span tags text.

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you post the url of the page you're parsing?

Comment: Check out next_sibling() if you find the first span you can find.next_sibling() to get the next one.

Comment: @jmaloney13 here https://www.swiggy.com/delhi/biryani-collection?page=1

Comment: Got it. Do you want to print out the names and stars for each restaurant, or are you trying to scrape something else?

Comment: yes, i want to scrape names star and pricing and name were matching but since some of the card stars are missing I am not able to correctly sync those stars for names.